# Нужно ли тире перед "это" в данном случае?

Tags: тире

*По дрова ходить и лагерь охранять это обязанности Андрея?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно.

А в чём трудность? Перед ЭТО всегда ставится тире, если оно присоединяет составное именное сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже:
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106